# lua - Can I "clean up" a weak table without having to invoke the whole GC?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, lua

I have a table with weak references on its keys. I use it to "register" events:

```
local events = setmetatable({}, {__mode="k"})

function registerEvent(reference, callback)
  events[reference] = callback
end
```

Every once in a while I execute all the events that are "current"; this is, I parse the `events` table and execute its callback.

```
function launchEvents()
  for reference,callback in pairs(events)
    callback(reference)
  end
end
```

This setup generally works just fine. Once a reference has stopped being used, it gets garbage-collected and its callback disappears from `events`.

Problem is - sometimes `launchEvents` is executed when a reference has been eliminated, but the Garbage Collector has still not run. In that case, I have some "phantom references" in `events`, and callbacks executed for objects that basically don't exist any more. For example, I create a button and associate it a "click" event. Then I remove the button (set it to nil). For a second or so, I'm still able to "click it", which is a shame.

The only fix I could find was manually running the GC inside launchEvents:

```
function launchEvents()
  collectgarbage()
  for reference,callback in pairs(events)
    callback(reference)
  end
end
```

But this seems a bit overkill. `launchEvents` could be being called many times per second. I'm invoking the full garbage collection cycle just to clean up one table.

Is there an alternative to this approach? Can I "garbage collect" or "clean up" just one weak table?

PS: I'm in Lua 5.1, by the way

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your program is quite different (although related) and much larger. With automatic memory management, removal of an object is nondeterministic and thus shouldn't have semantic impact, if that can be avoided at all. Instead, you need a way to "remove" (for all *semantic* purposes - e.g. being displayed and clickable) the object independent from garbage collection.

Comment: I would like not having to be explicit about "removing". If at all possible, I'd like to limit it to simply setting a reference to nil. On this case, "events" are pretty much "subdued" to references; really "secondary". I view references as "too important to mingle with the events".

Comment: You'll have to be explicit. The only thing that's implicit is that the GC *may* remove objects not (strongly) referenced any more. In fact, not collecting at all is valid and shouldn't break any well-written programs aside from them likely running out of memory. Besides, I bet you many places in your code have more than one reference to some widget (possibly implicitly, e.g. temporary references or funciton parameters).

Comment: That's actually a very good point. The callbacks themselves might still be referencing tables implicitly - via closures. hmm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua's garbage collector doesn't work that way. You can run it incrementally by calling `lua_gc` with `LUA_GCSTEP`. But that's no guarantee that it will investigate any particular object.

Your design is fundamentally flawed. If you want to collect a bunch of events, then execute them, then collect a new bunch of events, and then execute those, then you have to do that. You need to explicitly *throw away* the old events; don't just stick them in a weak table and expect GC to `nil` out the references.

GC is not like allocation/deallocation in C and C++. It is irregular and undependable. You should not rely on it for actual design functionality.

Comment: I guess I will have to continue with my current setup, even if it feels less automatic than it should. Oh, well. Thanks.